# Multithreading/Multiprocessing to avoid response timeout

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, twilio

I'm using `Twilio`'s SMS gateway to respond to customers incoming text messages.

I have the system set up so every time someone sends a text to my Twilio number, a HTTP post request is being sent to my server, where I then process it and return a response, which Twilio will send out to the customer.

However, my processing takes quite some time (roughly 20 seconds) during which I receive a timeout from Twilio.

I was thinking about a way to prevent the timeout. How could I speed up the processing time? The part that takes longest is me uploading some images. I was thinking that I could possibly start that process in a different thread. My server only has 1 core, so would multi-threading benefit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't try to respond back to customer on the Twilio post. Just capture the details in the post and queue it for background processing and respond back to Twilio immediately. And from your background process respond to your customer via sms using twilio api.

You may want to checkout celery or something similar for background task queue processing. http://www.celeryproject.org/

Comment: Twilio developer here! You might also consider using Redis-Queue if Celery is too heavyweight for your taste. A recent Python post on our blog used it: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/11/international-space-station-notifications-with-python-redis-queue-and-twilio-copilot.html